# How to protect specific file with htpassword using php?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm including a js file in my index.php file. When I view the source of index.php  and click on the js link, js file gets opened up. Is it possible to prevent users from opening js files from the view source page using .htaccess?

Comment: If you're asking for a way to allow a JavaScript file to be served to users but stop them from using View Source on it, that's not possible. However, if you use something like Webpack/Uglify it will at least mangle the JavaScript to make it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer - No

**Long answer**

JavaScript is a client side scripting language. It means the source gets downloaded to the user's browser and gets executed in the browser itself. So preventing access to js file means the it will not be executed.

However, some services like [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) helps you to make your code obscure so that no one can understand what does it do. But they will still be able to see and reuse your code.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is always readable for endusers. You can choose to scramble the javascript, so it is hard to read for humans.